# SSL connect error/crash under strange circumstances

Tags: c++, dynamic-library

When using libQuickMail in the shared object, the application crashes when loading from that so.

Say I have two programs:

program 1 is a program that loads a shared object. We'll call this program "prog1" and the shared object "so1". If relevant, the whole thing is a C++ Crow framework (multithreaded) application.

program 2 is just a single file main function. We'll call this "prog2".

Both so1 and prog2 use the same libquickmail code specified in the docs, specifically this one:

```cpp
quickmail_initialize();
quickmail mailobj = quickmail_create("[SENDER_EMAIL]","libquickmail test e-mail");
quickmail_set_body(mailobj, "This is a test e-mail.\nThis mail was sent using libquickmail.");
quickmail_add_to(mailobj, "[RECEIVER_EMAIL]");


const char *errmsg = quickmail_send(mailobj, "[SMPT_ADDRESS]", [SMTP_PORT], "[SENDER_EMAIL]", "[PASSWORD]");
if (errmsg != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending e-mail: %s\n", errmsg);
}

quickmail_destroy(mailobj);
```

prog2 runs just fine, however when prog1 tries to run the loaded so1, it either crashes or throws an SSL connect error. This doesn't happen when I move the code directly to prog1, though, however that isn't a viable solution.

Any suggestions/reasons as to why this would happen?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you specify on which platform this was, with which compiler and which version of libquickmail. Also note that libquickmail relies on libcurl to do SSL.

Comment: linux debian, g++, latest available from sourceforge, currently update 2022/04/09. I know about libcurl, but then again, it works just fine in the other program. I also opened the issue with the crow framework devs. In the meantime I already fixed it with a workaround